# I don't like him any; you can't fool me any. "Any"?

Tags: word-usage, synonyms, single-word-requests

What's the function of "any" in the title? Is it simply a synonym of "at all"? Why is its use so limited? For instance, *we don't go here at all* doesn't translate well to *we don't go here any* for me.

Is it specific to judgments of value? (like, care for, enjoy, etc.)

Comment: Yes, it means "at all". I'd call it dialectic. I associate it with Mark Twain's southerly characters, but I don't know where to look to get you a good answer to which contexts it can or can't be used in.

Comment: It's a quantification of (here) the amount of your liking for him, which is zero. You can also say _I don't like him much/a (whole) lot_. This construction is a member of the "minimal quantity" negative polarity item, like _drink a drop, eat a bite, do a thing, give a damn,_ etc.  None of these can be used grammatically outside a negative environment. Though that has changed for _could give a damn_, since it appears to have picked up negation by association.

Comment: @JohnLawler: It was on ELU where I read a post theorizing that `could give a damn`/`could care less` is kind of meta. The people saying it `could give a damn` whether this makes sense or not!

Comment: Maybe. It's certainly one interpretation; but nothing in language has only one interpretation. If you want the whole story, try [Language Log](http://itre.cis.upenn.edu/~myl/languagelog/archives/001202.html).

Comment: On grounds of its interpretation, I'd guess it is a verb modifier, like other adverbs of extent.  I find it to be perfectly normal midwestern English (I'm from Ohio originally) and one of a large variety of similar expressions, positive and negative (some, a lot, hardly at all, too much, a little, more than anything).

Answer (score 1):

I agree with Dan Bron that this is a dialectic usage. It makes sense to a native speaker; we know what is meant even if we don't use that turn of phrase ourselves. I believe it is common to a particular area of the South, but not the South as a whole. Considering that some of Twain's more formative years were spent in Hannibal, Missouri, I wouldn't be surprised if you could find it used there.

I'm having trouble finding the phrase using Google's ngrams. One notable example is in ["The Leisure Hour: An Illustrated Magazine for Home Reading"](https://books.google.com/books?id=U7DfAAAAMAAJ&pg=PA748&dq=%22do+not+like+him+any%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=hHVLVdK6G9HhoASNmIDgAQ&ved=0CCIQ6AEwATgK#v=onepage&q=%22do%20not%20like%20him%20any%22&f=false), where the author makes a similar point: it's not grammatical, but it's not difficult to understand.

Answer (score 1):

The use of ***any*** you refer to is when it is used as an adverb (dictionaries call it *informal* not *ungrammatical*:

From ODO:

[any](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/any)

> *US informal* At all (used alone, not qualifying another word):
>
> *I didn’t hurt you any.*
>
> *Yes he has hit into bad luck, and the new defensive approach hasn't helped him any.*

From LDOCE:

[any](http://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/any_2)

> *American English spoken* used with a verb to mean 'at all':
>
> *We tried talking to him but that didn't help any.*

As for the region(s) of the US, I don't have any evidence where it is used (yet), but two dictionary definitions should prove that it is grammatical.